Using a default config file while defining another via `--configfile` (that shares variables) [Snakemake]
I have a default config file that defines all of the variables necessary to run my workflow. It is included using the line configfile: 'config/defaults.yaml' in the Snakemake file. I would like to then give another configuration at runtime via the --configfile switch, which could overwrite some of these default values. This would be handy for two reasons:

I can define only a subset of the configuration variable in the runtime configfile.
Bash completion no longer complains about undefined values when I tab complete, rendering tab completion useless due to the garbage error message.

Is this sort of thing possible? The current behavior seems to disregard the values given in the runtime --configfile.

Well, it appears as though snakemake acts in the expected manner, where the variables given using --configfile overwrite the variables given in the configfile: line.
